# PGFPlots multiple plots issue with gnuplot

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

I am trying to produce multiple plots in one axis but always get error. It is interesting that file builds fine with  both plots separately.

Min code that does **not working**:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
        \addplot [no markers] gnuplot [raw gnuplot, color=red, id=xrd_H2] {
                set datafile separator comma;
                plot "Data/XRD/difrey/I74-3H2_norm.csv" every ::1 using 1:2};
        \addplot [no markers] gnuplot [raw gnuplot, color=blue, id=xrd_noH2] {
                set datafile separator comma;
                plot "Data/XRD/difrey/I74-3_norm.csv" every ::1 using 1:2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document ha
s been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}).

===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-o
n-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "test-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjo
b{test}\input{test}"' ========

! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "test-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{t
est}\input{test}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'test-figure0' (expec
ted one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system c
alls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also name
d 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error
messages can be found in 'test-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to t
ypeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.21 \end{tikzpicture}

?
! Emergency stop.
 ...

l.21 \end{tikzpicture}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on /home/volk/Documents/Work/CuZn_h-BN/test.log.
```

Min code that **working**:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
        \addplot [no markers] gnuplot [raw gnuplot, color=red, id=xrd_H2] {
                plot "Data/XRD/difrey/I74-3H2.dat" every ::1 using 1:2};
        \addplot [no markers] gnuplot [raw gnuplot, color=blue, id=xrd_noH2] {
                plot "Data/XRD/difrey/I74-3.dat" every ::1 using 1:2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Expect graph with 2 plots from 0 to 1.

Also the code that **working**:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
        \addplot [no markers] gnuplot [raw gnuplot, color=red, id=xrd_H2] {
                set datafile separator comma;
                plot "Data/XRD/difrey/I74-3H2_norm.csv" every ::1 using 1:2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Files:

[I74-3.dat](https://github.com/VolkovIlia/datafiles_for_ask/blob/main/raw_files/I74-3.dat)
[I74-3H2.dat](https://github.com/VolkovIlia/datafiles_for_ask/blob/main/raw_files/I74-3H2.dat)
[I74-3_norm.csv](https://github.com/VolkovIlia/datafiles_for_ask/blob/main/normalized_files/I74-3_norm.csv)
[I74-3H2_norm.csv](https://github.com/VolkovIlia/datafiles_for_ask/blob/main/normalized_files/I74-3H2_norm.csv)

Is it the **bug** or I'am doing something wrong?

Comment: For me this works perfectly fine (with commented `\tikzexternalize`; didn't test with). Unfortunately you didn't let us know *what* you consider "not working", i.e. state an error message or false output.

Comment: @StefanPinnow . Added log. Without `\tikzexternalize` pdflatex has out of memory error.